# Use git svn to roll back some changes on the svn server?

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

If I use `git svn dcommit` to commit a change, and then make a few changes and call `git svn dcommit` again, what is the simplest way to roll back the changes to the first version. If I were working only locally, then `git reset --hard HEAD^` would be fine, but I need this to work on the svn server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `git revert` to make a new git commit that un-does the earlier change.  Then `git-svn dcommit` that to the svn server.  You would not use your `git reset` solution if you had pushed to a remote git repo either:  It would confuse everyone who had pulled the intermediate revision that had your change.